# Replacing Copyright Dates with RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression I can use in a search and replace dialog to update copyright dates in a large number of AssemblyInfo.cs files.

The copyrights either have a range of dates or a single date. The associated text around the dates also varies.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2008 - 2010 My Company.")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2008 My Company.")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2005 -   2010 My Company.")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  1999")]
```

My regular expression so far is

```
Find: (\D*\d\d\d\d) *-*\d*(\D*)
Replace: $1 - 2011$2
```

As you can see from my results, the 2nd line is missing a space between 2011 and My Company.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2008 - 2011 My Company.")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2008 - 2011My Company.")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2008 - 2011 My Company.")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2008 - 2011")]
```

What am I doing wrong? I figure this has something to do with lazy/greedy expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Find: (.*?\d{4})(\s*-\s*\d{4})?(.*)
Replace: $1 - 2011$3
```

You can try it online [here](http://rubular.com/r/4Xe7JbxjEK).

Comment: Works like a charm. The only caveat is anything with a **Copyright 2011**, turns into **Copyright 2011 - 2011**. I'm not sure if that can be solved with a regex, so I'm just doing a double pass to fix those up after the fact.